# Need to query sharepoint list in InfoPath 2010, displaying unique work locations from a list and their job category counts

Tags: infopath

I have a list in SharePoint i'm trying to generate a report out of in InfoPath 2010. I need the Work Location and the Job Cateogory fields. Work Location could have multiple occurrences as these are job postings. Same with Job Categories. What i would like is a unique list of all Work Locations and then beside them the breakdown of how many instances in each job category. Like this:

```
Work Location            Job Category 1            Job Category 2           Job Category 3
Edmonton                 2                         8                        2
Calgary                  1                         0                        3
```

The complications arise in that Job Category is a single column, I'll know what Job Categories to filter for in the report though. The other complication is that i will need to display unique Work Locations. Any ideas? I'm fearing there's no no-code solution for this and that i'll have to crack open Visual Studio.